# Selenium: Get Attribute Value Based on Visible Text?

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm using Java and Selenium. I know I could get visible text using the getText() method/ For example, if I supply the ID (via XPath or CSS) I could do getText() on this to get visible text. But what if I want to do the opposite. Let's say I know what the visible text is and I want to use the text to find another attribute? For example, let's say I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="" title="Card"/>
<div id="99999cardName" class="cardName editInline" title="Click to edit">ZZZ</div>
<div id="99999cardNumber" class="cardNumber">4590 6565 6565 6565</div>
```

In this example, suppose I knew the value `4590 6565 6565 6565` and I wanted to get the value `99999cardNumber` - how would I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xpath in such a way that it contains text of that element. Here's how to do it -

```
String idVal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'4590 6565 6565 6565')]")).getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(idVal);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. text() is like looking for visible text? Similar to @Id but instead @text?

Comment: There is no `@text` as xpath selector in selenium. `@text` is `text()`. So the above example should work for you. `text()` gets the value inside the html element you specify.

Comment: And if I wanted to do the same for a webelement I already found? Such as WebElement element;

Comment: Then you need to manually compare the text of the found WebElement with the text value using `getText()` and then later get the attribute of it. I guess there is no shortcut for getting the attribute of an already found WebElement by using its text value. If you can give an example of what you need exactly, then i can try it out.

Comment: @NetNanny, XPath (and selenium) does support `@text`, but it means _"get attribute with name `text`"_, similar to `@id`, and if used in a place where the value is needed, it will return the value of the attribute: `x[@id = 'tst']`. The expression `text()` is called a _NodeTest_, which returns a text node and is more similar to `*` and can be used the same way. To get all the text nodes to any depth of a node, use the `string(...)` function. Attribute nodes do not have text node children, but element nodes do.

Comment: @NetNanny, the expression above can also be written as `//div[. = '4590 6565 6565 6565']`, with the subtle difference that this will look into all descendants (i.e., if text is inside `<p>` or `<span>` it will still find it), but `text()` will only look at _immediate text node children_.

Comment: @Abel - Thanks. ANd what would be the equivalent of `//div[. = '4590 6565 6565 6565']` in CSS?

Comment: @netnanny None, look ahead is not supported in css for performance reasons